# Object reference not set to an instance error

Tags: c#, object

I can't figure out why this keeps happening. I'm a beginner but to me there is a reference set to an instance. I had trouble at first getting the class to have a size for the array which is now set to 100

Here is my code.

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    SalesmanClass[] salesmen = new SalesmanClass[100];


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textBox6.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
        {


            for (int i = 0; i <= salesmen.Length; i++)
            {

                if (salesmen[i] == null)
                {
                    salesmen[i].name = textBox6.Text; // error happens here when i enter something into the form it says
                    //Object reference not set to an instance of an object error
                    break;

                }

            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Input a Name");
        }

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < salesmen.Length; i++)//var salesmen in salesmen)
        {
            names.Add(salesmen[i].Name);// same problem here
        }
        listBox1.Items.Add(names);

    }

    private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

**SalesmanClass.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public class SalesmanClass
{

    public string name;
    public string cNum;
    public string Email;
    public string address;
    public string gArea;
    public int tSales;

    public SalesmanClass()
    {
        name = null;
        cNum = null;
        Email = null;
        address = null;
        gArea = null;


    }
```

Comment: You don't need to declare your strings as null in the SalesmanClass() initializer, they are initialized as empty anyway. Also, just call it Salesman, we already know it is a Class from the declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remember that this line doesn't create any new SalesmanClass objects, only 100 references of type SalesmanClass.

```
SalesmanClass[] salesmen = new SalesmanClass[100];
```

I think you want:

```
if (salesmen[i] == null)
{
    salesmen[i] = new SalesmanClass();
    salesmen[i].name = textBox6.Text;
    break;
}
```

[EDIT]
Lander beat me to it. What I would suggest is you use a `List`, the you don't have to worry about "empty spots"

```
List<Salesman>() salesmen = new List<Salesman>();
```

And then replace your `for loop` code with simply:

```
if (textBox6.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
{
    salesmen.Add(new Salesmane() { name = textBox6.Text } );
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Input a Name");
}
```

You use this further down in `List<string> names`.

You might have to declare getters and setters on your properties:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I would also make these property names CamelCase since that is the accepted standard.

You'll need to update your button2_click to use `Count` instead of `Length` or use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (Salesman salesman in salesmen)
{
names.Add(salesman.Name);
}
```

You can also use LINQ to simplify, this does exactly the same ting:

```
List<string> names = salesmen.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it teaches some better practices, and will speed up your code by not requiring you to iterate over your array to find a free index.

Comment: @jammykam if i changed it to a list would i be able to use

`listbox1.DataSource = salesmen;`

Comment: Yes, you can use it in exactly the same. I very rarely use arrays, Lists are more robust. Thanks @Lander, you're kind.

Comment: @jammykam I'm a little confused with this, I need to get rid of `SalesmanClass[] salesmen = new SalesmanClass[100];` and replace is with `var salesmen = new List<Salesman>();` because one is an array and one is a list so I can't have both. When i try to make it a list, the compiler says that `var` may only appear within a local variable devlaration

Comment: Ahhh yes, I'll update the code, just declare it List<Salesman> salesmen = new List<Saleman>()

Comment: @ Jammykam Now getting something strange, I've Changed the code here are some links [Form1.cs](http://codepad.org/ExeJV04p) [SalesmanClass.cs](http://codepad.org/2MmFPpJC). When I click my `button2` all that appears in the listbox is `Collection` [Image Here](http://imgur.com/x2Rykz8)

Comment: Get rid `List<string> names` and in the `foreach` add directly to the listbox. See [updated Form1.cs code](http://codepad.org/AFMBn76S) and simplify your [SalesmanClass to this](http://codepad.org/yHAMAfWG). I renamed a few variables so be sure to check everything.

Comment: @jammyKam Thankyou for your patience, I wish i could do more to show my appreciation.

Comment: @jammyKam actually one more question :P with `salesmen.Add(new Salesmane() { name = textBox6.Text } );` am I able to reference that somehow. Such as if i needed to add some sales data that is referenced by the name i used. So in the future I can find out who has the highest sales out of all the salesmen

Comment: I wouldn't rely on name unless you can guarantee it wold be unique, and presume you would store this in a database with unique id's? Anyway, [you could use LINQ](http://codepad.org/KPhuFucc)

Answer (score 4):

You use the `==` operator in your `if` statement, meaning that if the salesman IS null, set its name. I believe you meant that if the salesman is *not* null (`!=`). You're also going to encounter an `index out of range` exception in your for loop, so I've fixed that here as well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < salesmen.Length; i++)
{

    if (salesmen[i] != null)
    {
        salesmen[i].name = textBox6.Text; // error happens here when i enter something into the form it says
        //Object reference not set to an instance of an object error
        break;

    }

}
```

If you *did* mean for that instance to be null, perhaps you want something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < salesmen.Length; i++)
{

    if (salesmen[i] == null)
    {
        salesmen[i] = new SalesmanClass();
        salesmen[i].name = textBox6.Text; // error happens here when i enter something into the form it says
        //Object reference not set to an instance of an object error
        break;

    }

}
```

In your `button2_Click` method, you are encountering the same issue because you aren't skipping the `null` salesmen. You can also see that I commented that I changed the field which you are accessing from `Name` to `name` since in the class which you posted, there is no `Name` field.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> names = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < salesmen.Length; i++)//var salesmen in salesmen)
    {
        if (salesmen[i] != null)
        {
            names.Add(salesmen[i].name); // changed from .Name to .name
        }
    }
    listBox1.Items.Add(names);

}
```

Comment: but if it is not null then it will pass over it, i want it to find a spot in the array that is null in the spot put what ever is in the textbox into salesmen[i].name

Comment: ah, okay, so i need to make a new object everytime.

Comment: @BobJones correct. You need to make a new object because initializing the array does not initialize any indexes in the array. It simply allocates an array with 100 free slots for salesmen.

Comment: im also getting the same error in button2_click method could you please take a look?

Comment: Use a list for salesmen like a suggested below, it will solve your button2 issue

Comment: @BobJones I've updated my answer. As jammykam said, using a list will probably be better suited for you *unless* you are going to always have 100 salesmen. By using a list you can ensure that every salesman in the list is created by only adding them when they're initialized.

Comment: Just realized we both missed it, it should be `salesmen[i].name = textBox6.Text` :-/

Comment: @jammykam ah hahaha good catch. I originally wrote part of this on my phone (which included the .name) then rewrote it on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

if an object reference error occurs check whether the variable u pass is correctly matching the correct index eg : If you are using Grid check whether the variable u access correctly pointing the index of the grid.

```
int StudID = 
Convert.ToInt32(editableItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editableItem.ItemIndex]
["StudID"].ToString());
```